# Could not resolve the foundation model from the provided model identifier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-bedrock, claude

I am experimenting with the Claude models based on this lab: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-bedrock-aistylist-lab

I am sending Claude 2 a prompt with 115,551 *characters* in. So worst case scenario, this is well within the token limits. But I am regularly getting timeouts when using Claude 2 so want to try with Claude 1.2 and see if that is more stable.

When I try to call Claude 1.2 I get:

> ValueError: Error raised by bedrock service: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the InvokeModel operation: Could not resolve the foundation model from the provided model identifier.

For testing, I'm using the `intro to bedrock` notebook: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-bedrock-aistylist-lab/blob/main/aistylist/intro_to_bedrock.ipynb

- If I use
  `modelId = "anthropic.claude-v2:1"` then I get a response from the LLM
- If I use
  `modelId = "anthropic.claude-v1:3"` then, as expected, I get a

> ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the InvokeModel operation: The provided model identifier is invalid.

response because this is not a valid version

- If I use
  `modelId = "anthropic.claude-v1:2"` then I get this error message:

> Could not resolve the foundation model from the provided model identifier.

This indicates that the v1.2 is recognized as a valid identifier, but there is a problem with accessing the model.

Anyone had any success in access Claude v1.2 these days on Bedrock?

Comment: If you try the CLI command "aws bedrock list-foundation-models", you should get a list of models with their ModelIds. Maybe the ModelId is different than you expect and that will help.

Comment: Thanks - that helped: here are the supported Claudes:
"anthropic.claude-instant-v1:2:100k",
"anthropic.claude-instant-v1",
"anthropic.claude-v1",
"anthropic.claude-v2:0:18k",
"anthropic.claude-v2:0:100k",
"anthropic.claude-v2:1:18k",
"anthropic.claude-v2:1:200k",
"anthropic.claude-v2:1",
"anthropic.claude-v2",

There is a anthropic.claude-instant-v1:2:100k but I get a different error when trying to use that one. Still, it seems you helped answer the question @rlhagerm: the `aws bedrock list-foundation-models` does not include all the versions that the UI claims.

Answer (score 0):

There is no model `anthropic.claude-v1:2` currently available on Bedrock. I think by referring to `anthropic.claude-v1:2` you are referring to `anthropic.claude-instant-v1`

[image: Claude Instant v1.2]

More info on available models on bedrock and their Id's: [Amazon Bedrock Base Model IDs(on-demand throughput)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/model-ids-arns.html)

Comment: The question is about v1.2; also the link was broken for me: ```Check if there is a typo in kismeta-clouddesk.aka.corp.amazon.com. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN```

Comment: Let me edit my answer. I think by referring to `claude 1.2` you are referring to `anthropic.claude-instant-v1`

Comment: Yep this sounds more credible. The puzzling thing is that I get a different error messages: When looking for a model that I know doesn't exist (e.g. 1.3) I get an error message that it's an invalid model id. This makes sense. But when I tried. with 1.2 I got a different error message that implied the model id was valid. Either way, I get yet another different error message again when I tried the claude-instant versions. For now the safest course of action is to keep character count to much much lower than the theoretical limit and stick with latest 2.1 version

Comment: Ahah. Best if you can open an issue at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues